# Dockerfile apt-get install - 503 service unavailable

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt

Does anyone have a robust solution to prevent periodic 503 service unavailable errors from apt-get in a Dockerfile?

I've tried pointing to different mirrors in the `/etc/apt/services.list` file, but this sometimes causes other issues (warnings/errors relating to unsigned repositories, for example).

I'd like to use the `APT::Acquire::Retries` (or is it just `Acquire::Retries`?) option in either my `apt.conf` file or as a separate file in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory, but no matter how I write it (e.g., `APT::Acquire::Retries "20";`) it doesn't seem to help. The man page explanation is [here](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html). My Dockerfile builds still fail after a 503, and I don't see any indication that it is using multiple retries.

Here's a snippet of the error message, if that helps. Note that a few lines it pulled successfully from the same server, a few lines above the error. Also if I go to the server FTP page in my browser, I can download the same package that fails the Dockerfile build.

Output snippet:

```
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 xfonts-encodings all 1:1.0.4-2 [573 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 xfonts-utils amd64 1:7.7+3ubuntu0.16.04.2 [74.6 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 xfonts-base all 1:1.0.4+nmu1 [5914 kB]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 xserver-common all 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 xvfb amd64 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8 [777 kB]
[91mE: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8_all.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

p.s. It doesn't just happen with `xvfb` - that just happens to be the one I copied here.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a lot of confusion between `APT::Acquire::Retries` and `Acquire::Retries`, but the latter works for me.  i.e.

```
echo 'Acquire::Retries "20";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80-retries;
```